# Google chrome another shortcut for Enter key

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, shortcuts

I want to make everything with my left hand shortcuts. For this I'm searching a shortcut for Enter character in google chrome. Sometimes I want to search something or paste a url to address bar and push to enter. My right hand is on the mouse and mouse is a little far to keyboard. I don't want to move up my right hand, push to enter and move back to mouse. This is time waste. Is there a shortcut for Enter button? For example can I assign CTRL+G (Go) or CTRL+E (Enter) for "search or go to url" action?

This thing is important for me becouse I want to be fast. Thanks.

Comment: Why downvote? This is a normal question I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Platform-independent solution**

Install the [Vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium) extension and customize the keybindings. The below example clears the default Vimium bindings and maps the keybindings to the asker's preferences: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to open the clipboard's URL in the current tab and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> copy the current URL to the clipboard

```
# Insert your preferred key mappings here
unmapAll
map <a-g> openCopiedUrlInCurrentTab
map <a-c> copyCurrentUrl
```

**Windows solution**

Using [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com), the following script will allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to function as the enter key only when Chrome is the active window.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Chrome.exe
^e::Send {ENTER}
```

I'm assuming that you are using Windows 7 or later.

Comment: I edited my answer to include another solution possibility. There are also versions of AutoHotkey for Ubuntu.

Comment: I added this to "Custom key mapping" section but doesn't work: # Insert your preferred key mappings here.
unmapAll
map <c-q> <enter>

Comment: I believe that Ctrl+q is an operating system shortcut, so it may not be able to be overridden. Have you tried another key?

Comment: I accepted your answer but my exactyle solution is that: # Insert your preferred key mappings here.
unmapAll
map <a-g> openCopiedUrlInCurrentTab
map <a-c> copyCurrentUrl
Can you paste these to your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's been a while but I too would like to know if there is a minimalistic solution. I keynavigate with my left hand, and moues navigate with my right, so I can see why it's pertinent to have an execute/return/enter function linked to the left side of the keyboard. Your question is the top result on this subject!